# How to skip a tab on swipe if tab is "disabled"

Tags: flutter, dart, tabbar

I have a TabBar with 4 Tabs. If content for either Tab is empty, I'd like for said Tab to get a "disabled" state, both onTap **and** swipe.

I've managed to disable by onTap, but yet to be able to "skip" the Tab if it's disabled.

For example: If there are no lists under `Ready`, I'd like to skip **from** `InProgress` to `Archived` **on swipe.**

```
void onTap(int index) {
    if (disabledTabIndex != null) {
      setState(() {
        _controller.index = index == disabledTabIndex
            ? _controller.previousIndex
            : index;
      });
    }
  }
```

```
TabBar(
   tabs: [
      Tab("Show all"),
      Tab("InProgress"),
      Tab("Ready"),
      Tab("Archived"),
   ],
   onTap: (int index) => onTap(index),
   controller: _controller,
),
```

```
TabBarView(
   controller: controller,
   children: [
      CustomListView(list: unfilteredList),
      CustomListView(list: filteredListByInProgress),
      CustomListView(list: filteredListByReady),
      CustomListView(list: filteredListByArchived),
   ],
),
```

I have added `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` to `TabBarView`, however this disables swipe **completely**. Which is not the outcome I want. I want to just **skip** content.

```
TabBarView(
   controller: controller,
   physics: controller.index == disabledTabIndex ? NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() : null,
   children: [
      CustomListView(list: unfilteredList),
      CustomListView(list: filteredListByInProgress),
      CustomListView(list: filteredListByReady),
      CustomListView(list: filteredListByArchived),
   ],
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try refactor your tabs with `GestureDetector` or `InkWell` and give your func `onTap` to them.

Comment: In terms of a11y, I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).